# Divide by zero exception using awk

Tags: awk, arithmetic

i have values stored in variables var1=6 and var2=4, i am trying to divide them with a precision of 2 and store the result in a variable `var`,

```
var=`awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", $var1/ $var2}'`
```

when i perform the above operation i get
`awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted`

can someone please point out what exactly i am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: `awk` is really needed ? `var=$((echo scale=2 ; echo $var1 / $var2 ) | bc)`

Comment: unfortunately yes, as i am running an automation script in shared environment which doesn't recognize `bc`, so when i try using the same command that u suggested it says `bash: bc: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `-v var=value` to pass variable to awk.

thus

```
awk -v var1="$var1" -v var2="$var2" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n",var1/var2}'
```

give

```
1.50
```

and

```
var=$(awk -v var1="$var1" -v var2="$var2" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n",var1/var2}')
```

set value.

you need

- `-v var1="$var1"` to turn bash's $var1 to awk's var1
- use `var1` in `awk` (no need for `$`, `$var1` with var1=6 would be `$6`'s value)
- <s>`echo` to provide input to `awk` (or else awk would hang waiting for input)</s> (forget about BEGIN in awk)

Comment: thank you for the answer and detailed explanation

Comment: echo is not needed by the awk standard.

Comment: @jlliagre yes, `echo` is not needed but then `BEGIN` is.

Comment: You might want to make that `printf "%.2f\n",(var2 ? var1/var2 : 0)` or similar to protect against divide by zero error when `var2` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can pass the contents of the `$var1` and `$var2` *shell* variables as arguments to your `awk` script, and access them in the script via the special `ARGV` array variable:

```
var=$(awk -- 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", ARGV[1] / ARGV[2]}' "$var1" "$var")
```

Or you can export the `var1` and `var2` shell variables to the *environment* for `awk` to retrieve them via its `ENVIRON` array variable:

```
var=$(
  export var1 var2
  awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", ENVIRON["var1"] / ENVIRON["var2"]}'
)
```

In the general case, it's often preferable to use `ARGV`/`ENVIRON` over `-v` or `var=value` arguments to pass arbitrary data as those latter ones mangle backslash characters (not really an issue here for numbers though).

Embedding the expansion of the shell variable in `awk`'s code argument should be avoided as it amounts to a code injection vulnerability. Same for [forgetting to quote parameter expansions in arguments to `-v`](/a/171347).

Note that if the shell is `ksh93` or `zsh`, you don't need `awk` at all here:

```
printf -v var %.2f '1.*var1 / var2' # zsh
var=${ printf %.2f '1.*var1 / var2'; } # ksh93
```

(where the multiplication with `1.` forces the evaluation to be done as floating point).

However note that you'd need to [sanitise the contents of those variables or otherwise that would be another arbitrary code execution vulnerability](/q/172103) if the contents of those variables weren't under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Should you really want to use `awk`, which is questionable for such a simple script but would make sense for a more complex one, here are two ways to  overcome the issue:

1. just replace the simple quote by double quotes. The simple ones prevent the dollar expansion. That introduces other issues like the requirement for existing double quotes to be escaped and the same requirement if you want to use fields in `awk`).

   ```
   var=`awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\n\", $var1/ $var2}"`
   ```
2. pass the variables to `awk` the right way:

   ```
   var=$(awk -v var1="$var1" var2="$var2" 'BEGIN {printf("%`.2f\n",var1,var2)}')
   ```

Comment: thank you, the explanation of single quotes and double quotes actually helped in understanding the dollar expansion using `awk`